# Delete a dictionary item based on a value from a list iteration

Tags: python

I have tried the following:

```
losers = ['e', 'b']
candidates_and_fp_votes = {'a': 24, 'b': 0, 'c': 17, 'd': 23, 'e': 0}
for i in losers:
    del candidates_and_fp_votes[losers[i]]
print(candidates_and_fp_votes)
```

This just returns the error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I would like to iterate over losers and delete every item in `candidates_and_fp_votes` which has a key in `losers`

I expect an output of:

```
{'a': 24, 'c': 17, 'd': 23}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for i in losers` does **not** generates **indices**, but the **elements** of `losers`.

Comment: Thanks, I found out it was just a silly error by me.

Comment: Don't change the title when the question is answered, accepting an answer lets everyone know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
losers = ['e', 'b']
candidates_and_fp_votes = {'a': 24, 'b': 0, 'c': 17, 'd': 23, 'e': 0}
final_dict = {a:b for a, b in candidates_and_fp_votes.items() if a not in losers}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 24, 'c': 17, 'd': 23}
```

Comment: @TIC-FLY it is a shorter solution.

Comment: I know and that's why I have ticked it and used that in my code instead of the other options.

Comment: @TIC-FLY glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

`i` is the list element, not an index. It should be:

```
del candidates_and_fp_votes[i]
```

or it should be:

```
for i in in range(len(losers)):
```

if you really want the indexes for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, i found out that it was just a silly mistake from me.

Answer (score 1):

When you are iterating over an object (in this case a list called 'losers') the variable `i` is actually the data in the object not the index of the data like you might see in other languages (c/c++). So in the first iteration of the for loop `i == 'e'` then the second `i == 'b'` then the loop would end because there is no more data.

So all you need to do is change losers[i] to just i:

`del candidates_and_fp_votes[i]`

Here is the complete code with the line fixed.

```
losers = ['e', 'b']
candidates_and_fp_votes = {'a': 24, 'b': 0, 'c': 17, 'd': 23, 'e': 0}
for i in losers:
    del candidates_and_fp_votes[i]
print(candidates_and_fp_votes)
```

Comment: Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it, don't just post code.

Comment: Thanks, I found out it was just a silly error by me.

Answer (score 1):

your index `i` is a string, not an integer.
You could do something like this:

```
losers = ['e', 'b']

candidates_and_fp_votes = {'a': 24, 'b': 0, 'c': 17, 'd': 23, 'e': 0}

for i in losers:

     if i in candidates_and_fp_votes:
          del candidates_and_fp_votes[i]

print(candidates_and_fp_votes)
```